# PHP error log not updating

Tags: php, error-logging

My apache error log is located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. I've been using it to debug a simple PHP script I'm writing.

Now, suddenly it isn't catching anything. I've tried putting in known errors like calling functions that don't exist and nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by restarting Apache. It turns out that I "broke" it myself by editing the log file.
Note to self: *Do not do that.*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check that Apache still has access to this folder and this file.

Comment: How woud I do that, and where would I go to give it access if it somehow lost it?

Comment: You need to connect to the server with SSH. Then use the chmod command to check the folder and file's rights. They need to be set to 0777.

Comment: I didn't think of checking the permissions, but I fixed it anyway, thanks.